# Getting "Template is missing" when using XmlMarkup builder in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, templates, routes

I'm learning Rails, and I'm trying to get a XML output of my update ActiveRecord. This is my `routes.rb`:

```
Sparklizer::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :updates
  get "updates/new"
  get "updates/list"
  get "home/index"
  match "updates/xml/:id" => "updates#xmlOut"
end
```

`match "updates/xml/:id" => "updates#xmlOut"` is where I try to output XML. This is the `xmlOut` method:

```
def xmlOut
        render :layout => false

        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml'
        @xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
        @update = Update.find(params[:id])
        xml.instruct!  :xml, :version=> "1.0"
            xml.declare!  :DOCTYPE, :html,  :PUBLIC, "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN", "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"

            xml.update {
                for data in @update
                    xml.data do
                        xml.title(data.title)
                        xml.description(data.description)
                    end
                end
            }
    end
```

When running and accessing to `/updates/xml/2` I get

```
Template is missing

Missing template updates/xmlOut, application/xmlOut with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "/Users/pablo/Documents/Workspace/Sparklizer/app/views"
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to render your xml without having a view file. To make it work, you would have to render your xml 'inline'. From the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render):

```
render :inline => "xml.p {'Horrid coding practice!'}", :type => :builder
```

But rendering inline is regarded as a bad practice.

So you should better use the [respond_with](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_with) construct. Something like this (adjust as needed):

```
def xmlOut
  @update = Update.find(params[:id])

  respond_with(@update) do |format|
    format.xml  { render :xml => @update }
  end
end
```

There's also a [railscast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3) covering this.

Comment: I added at the end of the method `respond_with(@xml)`. Is this ok? It's not working too

Comment: That seems to work, though I get now `In order to use respond_with, first you need to declare the formats your controller responds to in the class level`, what that means?

Comment: That means you need to have this statement at the top of your controller: `respond_to :xml`. Also see the railscast, it covers the topic in an execellent way